# .htaccess multiple rules and exceptions

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a .htaccess file that has multiple rules to make the url's look "pretty".
This is the file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^property/([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?$ /property.php?ID=$1&Image=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^property$ /property.php [L]

RewriteRule ^enquire/([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?$ /enquire.php?ID=$1&Data=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^enquire$ /enquire.php [L]

RewriteRule ^contact/?$ /contact.php [L]
RewriteRule ^home/?$ /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(property|property/.*|enquire|enquire/.*|contact|contact/.*|home|home/.*)$
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /custompages.php?ID=$1 [L]
```

The first set of rules works for `property`, `enquire`, `contact` and `home`.
If the url is not one of these, e.g. `www.foo.com/about-us`, I want it to call the file `custompages?ID=about-us` but with this code, it isn't working. I am quite new to using .htaccess files and I can't figure out what the issue is myself.

Answer (score 0):

Your last rule is not correct. Change that to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /custompages.php?ID=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Does this URL load properly: `www.foo.com/custompages.php?ID=about-us` ?

Comment: This doesn't work `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(property|property/.*|enquire|enquire/.*|contact|contact/.*|home|home/.*)$
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /custompages.php?ID=$1 [L]`

But this does `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /custompages.php?ID=$1 [L]`

Comment: Sorry missed `!` in condition above, try it now.

Comment: I have fixed it, by eliminating the - before -d and -f